# Proper way to use a database class

Tags: c#, database, odbc

I've been searching for this for a little while now and cannot seem to find a way to accomplish my goal.

First, what I'm currently trying to code is a ticketing app for our IT department to use, mostly to help us keep track of what has and hasn't been done to different machines and some people that may need further training in the software that is used on site.  I have a few tables created to keep tracking of work performed, issues, and any relevant notes.  The final product will be more than a ticketing system, but a somewhat comprehensive IT support app.

My goal in the use is to have the tech "sign in" to the app by providing his/her username and password to our database system.  From there the tech's permissions will be loaded as to what a tech can and can't do with tickets.  When the tech would like to view tickets or edit tickets I want the app to load any relevant tickets (i.e. open tickets, closed tickets, PC tickets, printer tickets,...etc.).

I have a ticket class that contains all of the properties that are stored within the database, but my question is how to properly link the first sign on information to the ticket class.

For example in my class I have something like:

```
    public class ticket
    {
         public int TicketNumber {get;set;}
         public string Tech {get;set;}
         public string Category {get;set;}
         public string ReportedBy {get;set;}

         public void Save()
         {
            //Code to update record in DB
         }

         public void Create()
         {
            //Code to add a new record to DB
         }
     }
```

So, how do I properly get the class to where I can add the proper user name and password to this to include the tech's user name and password?  I've had similar projects working before, but I have pretty much always used another person's user name and password hard coded.  For this I would not want someone else using the application to be changing any of the ticket information if their user name and password was not valid for these tables.

Sorry for being wordy, but wanted to provide a basic look at what the app is in case someone has a better idea.  I am open to suggestions especially on proper ways to pass the sign on information from app to class then data back to app.

The database is an iSeries.  We use the IBM iSeries 32-bit ODBC driver to connect from Windows, if this helps.  Most of the coding will be done in C# using Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why would you store username/password as part of a ticket?

Comment: I don't want to store it as part of a ticket.  I'm trying to find the proper way of passing that information to the ticket class so that I can use it for the connection string to connect to the database.  Or is having a second class the proper way?

Comment: Ideally you'd setup your iseries to use the window domain so if the user is signed into windows their windows credentials will allow them access to the iseries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate class to hold to user:

```
public class TechUser
{
    public string UserName {get; private set;}
    public string Password{get; private set;}
    public TechUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

Then pass it in to the create function:

```
TechUser user = new TechUser("name", "pw");
ticket t = new ticket();
t.Create(user)
```

Comment: That could work really well.  I had a similar idea where I was building a class to hold the connection information and going to pass this to the desired method in the ticket class.  Your way would allow me to also store the tech's permission levels.  Thank you, I will let you know how it works when I back in to work to add it.

Comment: Yes, you generally want to pass your dependencies (things that are determined by outside factors, such as a connection string) in. So you want to pass the connection info into the database connection object, and pass the database connection object into the classes that use the connection.

Comment: OK perfect, that's what I had been trying to find.  Every example I was finding already had all the connection information in the method without passing anything.  In the earlier apps I made I had it hard coded which made a huge mess. (Spelling edit)

Comment: Yes, to add more details: It's common to gather of of these strings and user settings, either in main or a "Bootstrapper", and then pass properties of this down into the classes that needs them. This way you can easily change and mock things, such as users, connections etc. .